# Do you need to visualize geometrically when doing Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

When working on understanding Linear Algebra, and working on proofs and other exercises, is it important to think and visualize geometrically what is happening with the various objects (such as vector spaces, etc) or is it sufficient to simply think of them as algebraic operations? I have a hard time understanding the geometric visualization of some objects like vector spaces so I am wondering if that's critical to get or I can think of proofs and exercises algebraically and just focus on proofs from an algebraic perspective?

Comment: "I have a hard time understanding the geometric visualization of some objects like vector spaces" : you litterally *live in* a vector space.

Comment: Right but I have a hard time understanding geometrically what are examples of things that aren't vector spaces vs ones that are? Sort of geometrically picture the difference between what is a vector space and what is not? Also, on a more general level, I am just trying to understand if it's important to visualize geometrically everything that you do in linear algebra

Comment: Determining whether or not something is a vector space is an exercise in algebra, not geometry. The geometric intuition applies more to spaces where the "arrow" abstraction makes sense. For example, when dealing with vector spaces of polynomials or other functions, the geometry of adding directed line segments doesn't really apply.

Comment: @JohnDouma, so am I correct in understanding that the geometric intuition only is 1 interpretation of vector spaces? Do I follow correctly that from your viewpoint the geometric intuition is not particularly required to make progress in linear algebra?

Comment: That is correct. You use any insights you have to solve a problem, including geometry, but Linear Algebra is first and foremost algebra.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel like you're getting something from the geometric intuition, I wouldn't worry about it, especially when you're trying to get into the subject. Like basically any math topic, there are multiple entry points to linear algebra and in general its fine to think about the subject in the way that makes the most sense to you. That being said, if you can develop some geometric intuition that can be very helpful for getting a "feel" of the subject.

I'll also add that based on your username, you're probably interested in some very high dimensional settings where geometric intuition doesn't really get you anywhere anyways.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I am interested not necessarily only from an application to machine learning perspective but even from a pure math perspective as well